# No consigo sacar valores de un funcion fuera de la funcion en python

Tags: python, funciones, archivo

estoy elaborando un programa que saca valores de un archivo y con esos valores los saca para usarlos en otra función. El problema que me aparece es que me aparece en consola "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'float2' referenced before assignment" pero tengo definidas las variables de la función y las de clase y están referenciadas (o eso creo) adjunto el código para que lo vean y puedan orientarme.
Gracias de antemano.

'''

```
from io import open

ruta = "C:\\Users\\Eduardo\\Desktop\\CursoPython\\pildoras\\archivos\\Output- 
optBprueba\\1\\01-9_jrl80_RSS_1.log"

var1="Sum of electronic and zero-point Energies"

var2="Sum of electronic and thermal Energies"

var3="Sum of electronic and thermal Enthalpies"

var4="Sum of electronic and thermal Free Energies"

def recoge_datos(ruta):

    #abrimos el archivo
    with open(ruta, "r") as fname:
        linea= fname.readline()
        for lista in fname: 
        
            if var1 in lista:
                numero1 = lista[54:65]
                float1=float(numero1)
                float1= float1*627.503
            
            if var2 in lista:
                numero2 = lista[54:65]
                float2=float(numero2)
                float2= float2*627.503
               
            if var3 in lista:
                numero3 = lista[54:65]
                float3=float(numero3)
                float3= float3*627.503
            
            if var4 in lista:
                numero4 = lista[54:65]
                float4=float(numero4)
                float4 = float4 *627.503
                float4=float4
            
            linea= fname.readline()
            valores=[float1,float2,float3,float4] 
        return valores[:]  

 listado = [recoge_datos(ruta)]
 print(listado[:])
```

'''

Comment: Si tu código no entra al `if var2 in lista:` nunca vas a tener declarada la variable `float2`. Deberías declararlas fuera de los `if` para asegurarte de que existen, por ejemplo dándoles un valor inicial o añadiendo un `else` a los `if` para asegurarte de que la variable se declare también aunque no se cumpla la condición

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La causa inmediata es que las variables `float1, float2, float3, float4` no tiene valor asignados.

La solución inmediata es asignarles un valor al comenzar:

```
def recoge_datos(ruta):
    # abrimos el archivo
    float1 = float2 = float3 = float4 = 0
    with open(ruta, "r") as fname:
```

Pero hay problemas adicionales. Como sacas cada `floatN` de una línea distintas, no tiene sentido grabar *siempre*

```
valores = [float1, float2, float3, float4]
```

pues tendrás en todo momento una combinación de valores antiguos y nuevos. Lo lógico sería retrasar la asignación hasta tener los cuatro valores. Suponiendo que siempre vienen las cuatro líneas, tendrías que asignar sólo después de leer `float4`:

```
        if var4 in lista:
            numero4 = lista[54:65]
            float4 = float(numero4)
            float4 = float4 * 627.503
            float4 = float4
            
            valores = [float1, float2, float3, float4]
```

Además, estás descartando línea por medio del archivo, pues lo leido con

```
linea = fname.readline()
```

nunca es utilizado. Puede ser lo correcto, pero sin saber la estructura de los datos, es pura especulación.

Comment: Tenias toda la razón al no declararlos al inicio de la función por eso no me entraban en la lista. Lo de línea a línea es porque en cada fichero esos "var" están en líneas distintas de cada archivo.  Muchas gracias por la ayuda prestada. lo aprecio mucho =)